# How to send HTTP response (not request)?

Tags: python, http

I need to send an HTTP response like the one below using python. How can this be accomplished?

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# set up socket and connection (socket library)
while True:
    sock, addr = servSock.accept()
    sock.send("""HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
""");
    sock.close()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Do you know if there is a way to do it without sockets?